# Is there really "No Underwear In Space?"

Tags: star-wars, clothing

In Carrie Fisher's one-woman show, [“Wishful Drinking,”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wishful_Drinking) she mentions that **George Lucas wouldn’t let her wear a bra with her white costume in *Star Wars: A New Hope* because there was *[“no underwear in space.”](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hvVUMW_iUlw)***

Is this word-of-god canon, or have other *Star Wars* properties mentioned the existence of (let’s say human) characters (especially Leia) wearing underwear in the *Star Wars* universe, and Lucas was just being gross?

I’m most interested in Disney Canon -- **now that Lucas's private comment to Fisher has become more well-know through *Wishful Drinking*'s successes (on and off Broadway, as a book, and on film), has there been any underwear in the new canon?**

Multiple commenters have noted instances of underwear throughout the Extended Universe/Legends canon, but the ["Canon" portion of the Wookieepedia article about “Underwear”](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Underwear) (yes, there is one) only seems to list one allusion to underwear (it’s tighty-whiteys) in the current canon ([*Heir to the Jedi*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Heir_to_the_Jedi), though they are only theoretical, not literal underwear) and another mention in [a canon children’s book that also references a number of out-of-universe things.](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Empire_Strikes_Back:_So_You_Want_to_Be_a_Jedi%3F)

<sub>To unpack the *Heir to the Jedi* underwear mention for a second: in *Heir to the Jedi* (the **first** entry into Disney Canon) apparently a character meeting Luke Skywalker for the first time says: "You hear about someone blowing up the Death Star... you think someone like that is all about duty and righteousness and wears super-tight underwear." While this suggests that the concept of underwear **exists,** it's vague whether "super-tight" is the telling detail (as it would be in our underwear-wearing culture) or if it's "wearing...underwear" that is the telling detail in the possibly-underwearless Star Wars universe...</sub>

Comment: This would explain why Obi Won only left his robe behind.

Comment: +1 just for writing a question about underwear of SFF and actually making it a sensible one!

Comment: According to "The Making of Empire Strikes Back" - "*An article would appear in The San Diego Union about how fans had spotted a Wookiee, saying that Mayhew wore pink underwear beneath his costume."*

Comment: In the EU novels, there are literally dozens of examples of people wearing underwear. Too many to make into a sensible answer.

Comment: Having nearly finished Knights of the Old Republic video game, if you remove a characters clothing, they're left in underwear. There's also a cut scene of Bastila in just bra and panties.

Comment: I hadn't heard that - I heard that the reason she held down with gaffer's tape in lieu of traditional undergarments was a combination of her costume not allowing it and her being too *ahem* bouncy even with a bra on. Remember, the Sports Bra wasn't even invented until the late 70s.

Comment: George Lucas apparently gave Carrie this explanation:  "He has seen [Wishful Drinking] a couple of times and explained the thing about him saying there was no underwear in space. He explained that in space you get weightless so your flesh expands but your bra doesn’t: “So you get STRANGLED by your bra!” So that’s why I couldn’t wear a bra in the first Star Wars. He came backstage when I did the show in San Francisco and told me that. I said, ‘Really? Now I understand everything."

Comment: @Aith yeah George, uh huh..... Except every ship has perfect gravity simulators that never fail no matter how damaged the ship is.....

Comment: @dunraven - I find the notion ridiculous myself... but then I found this article: http://www.space.com/20730-human-body-spaceflight-weird-facts.html and I can't help but wonder if Lucas was referring to something like that and specifically, about potentially getting taller/changing size.  Strangled, though?  Seriously?

Comment: @Aith I just finished Mary Roach's really fantastic science-journalism book about life in space (*Packing for Mars* - hilarious read) and there's a lot on real-life astronaut logistics like underwear rotting off people in early space capsules because they didn't send extras, and she would definitely have mentioned bra strangulation because that is SO on-topic for her interests.

Comment: @Aith Let's face it: George knew how to make the most of science and the notion of imperfect knowledge in others for his own gain. Best wingman ever.

Comment: iirc she also says that in her commentary on the remastered version of New Hope DVD that was released in the early 2000's

Comment: [Beach Troopers](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Beach_trooper) from Lego Star Wars

Comment: We're talking _Disney_ here, so not only does underwear exist (which you'll probably never get to see, though), but also [purity rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ring_(South_Park)) ;)

Comment: @BenMiller haha nice link but gonna say bathing suits =/= underwear.

Comment: @unraven Well, Leia is one of the very few characters to go into space with no suit on—not that George Lucas could have possible know _that_ … 

Answer (score 17):

I know it's hard to see, but this is a picture of Anakin after waking up from his bad dreams

[image: anakin waking up WITH FREEHAND CIRCLE!!]

You can see that he is wearing some kind of tight, black garment on his legs. This seems to be at least his sleepwear, and as it is definitely not his normal robe.  This seems to be as close as we can find as to underwear in space, but I am still searching.  I would say, though, that this does a good enough job of proving Lucas wrong.

Comment: @ibid Sure, but then it would take so long to put the picture in for me...

Comment: I made one. Rollback to see it.

Comment: Ooh, this is great. But there's no way to know if he wears it under his robe or if he put them on just to go to bed, which would make them pajamas...

Comment: after watching the movie again last night, they are indeed pajama pants

Comment: @Skooba I'm sorry you had to do that

Comment: But Anakin is not out in space during that scene. He's on a planet. Now blast him off of Coruscant, and ...

Answer (score 11):

**I know... this is a stretch...**

It may depend on what you call "underwear" as we see in *The Force Awakens*; Finn has black undergarments beneath his trooper armor. Although it is full length, we here on Earth have "long underwear"...

[image: finny mcfinerson]

**ALSO**... I can't believe this was not mentioned in the comments at least... what do we consider this... a gold "bikini", but why would there be *swimwear* on a desert planet!!

[image: solid gold baby]

**In Addition** Luke is seen wearing some sort of undergarment resembling "tighty-whiteys" during his time in the bacta tank in *ESB*.

[image: luke dunk tank]

Comment: Slave Leia's outfit is clearly intended as outerwear to deal with Tatooine's excessive heat.

Comment: @DCShannon: Of course. It's strictly intended to be functional.

Comment: It is possible that the undergarments of Storm Trooper armor are actually ballistic cloth to help protect the wearer from impacts, explosions and other debris small enough to slip between the joints in the armor. This would make it more a part of the uniform than actual underwear.

Comment: Interesting ideas, though I sorta feel like if these really do count as underwear in the Star Wars universe (especially storm trooper underwear, which is partially visible through the armor), that suggests that traditional earth-style underwear maybe *doesn't* really exist... Pure speculation, but since earth underwear was intended to extend the life of your outerwear back in the days when people had one or two outfits, so maybe sweat-wicking self-cleaning  technological advancements in the galaxy far far away's textiles have long since evolved away from the need for underwear...

Comment: ...except when its part of battle armor that doesn't give full coverage, or in cases like the slave outfit or twi'lek dancer outfits where the classic earth underwear shapes are used for purely aesthetic reasons.

Comment: If you have to ask this "why would their be swimwear on a desert planet" you will never make it as a Hutt.

Comment: Finn is wearing *cargo pants* in this picture. Do you mean to tell me that in the future, women still don't have real pockets on *anything* and men get *cargo pockets* on their *underwear*?

Comment: @MissMonicaE Of course that isn't the insinuation. This is in the past, not the future.

Comment: @GorchestopherH I always assumed it was set in the future, and "a long time ago" was from the perspective of an even-farther-future narrator, but if it's the past, then I say, "In all the years since men had cargo pockets on their long johns, women can't get decent regular pockets on our pants?!?"

Comment: I'd advise putting the tank at the top, as I think it's your best example.

Comment: @MissMonicaE, that's a very odd assumption to make out of the plain English introduction, "A long time ago in a galaxy far, far away...."

Comment: @Wildcard To be honest I'm not sure why I assumed that. Maybe I assumed "scifi = future" before I actually saw Star Wars, and then filled in the rest to fit around the prefixed idea that "Star Wars = future"?